# Admin lte dropdown not working from root page but is on inner pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, adminlte

I am using admin lte for my dashboard however a strange issue with the drop down is its working in the inner pages but not the outter pages.

https://adminlte.io/

For My profile menu I am using

For example here it will work

```
 http://localhost:57038/MISObjects/Search
```

But here it wont
http://localhost:57038/MISObjects

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
   <!-- Left navbar links -->
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
            </li>

            <!-- SEARCH FORM -->
            <form asp-action="Search" asp-controller="MISObjects" method="post">

                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <select id="searchType">
                        <option value="1">All Cases</option>
                        <option value="2">My Cases</option>
                    </select>

                    <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Case Number" aria-label="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>


        </ul>

        <!-- Right navbar links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>


            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
                    <span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge">15</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
                    <span class="dropdown-item dropdown-header">15 Notifications</span>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i> 4 new messages
                        <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">3 mins</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                        <i class="fas fa-users mr-2"></i> 8 friend requests
                        <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">12 hours</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                        <i class="fas fa-file mr-2"></i> 3 new reports
                        <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">2 days</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Notifications</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-widget="control-sidebar" data-slide="true" href="#" role="button">
                    <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i>
                </a>
                </li>
            

    <!-- Notifications Dropdown Menu -->
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user-cog" style="font-size:24px;"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
        <a asp-action="Setup" asp-controller="Admin" asp-route-id="1" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fa fa-users-cog mr-2"></i> Settings

        </a>


        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {

            <a asp-action="Logout" asp-controller="MISObjects" class="dropdown-item">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt mr-2"></i> Logout
            </a>


        } else {
            <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer fa fa-sign-in-alt">Login</a>
            <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">Register</a>

        }
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

But for some reason its not working on the main page. Juqery is loaded fine and there is no errors on the console when i debug as proven by the screen shot below

Here is my scripts section

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="~/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="~/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>

<script src="~/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-validation/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!-- bootstrap color picker -->
<!-- Bootstrap Switch -->
<script src="~/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>


<script src="~/font-awesome/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="~/font-awesome/js/brands.js"></script>
<script src="~/font-awesome/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/select2/js/select2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)


<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true" defer></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true" defer></script>
</environment
```

Console Errors
There are no errors

Comment: "the inner pages but not the outter pages" About the inner pages, do you mean you are using the partial view? Where you add the JavaScript and the CSS reference, in the main page or inner page? In the root page, try to add the JavaScript and CSS reference in the header. Besides, try to clear the browser data and recheck it, make sure it is not the cache issue.

Comment: What i mean by inner pages is anything aftherr the / so for example I would call /MISObjects and inner page that points to that layour file in the folder views -> MISObjects

Comment: I‘m still a bit confused about the inner page, since your application is an asp.net core mvc application and MISObjects is the the controller name, when the url is "http://localhost:57038/MISObjects/" it will display the Index page (be default, you could also check your route configure to check the default action method), and if the url is "http://localhost:57038/MISObjects/Search", it will display the Search page. Both the Index page and Search page are in the Views folder. So, do you mean you have add the Dropdown in these pages or in the layout page? Besides, what do you mean not working?

Comment: To be clear, you could capture some screenshot to explain more details  about the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same issues  I had a partial script being loading inside a view component which is not supported thus this was blocking the dropdown from working.

Do not use parialasync to load a component inside a another partial view.